# Showing a form in a COM visible DLL

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++, com, unmanaged

From unmanaged VC++ 6.0 I'm calling a COM visible .NET DLL.
From this DLL, I want to show a dialog.
I can get the DLL to register properly and work *if the methods don't call Form.show().* However, if the methods DO call form show, I cannot instantiate the DLL (I get 'class not registered error").

Anybody know what I need to do?

Comment: Pretty unclear, you'd have to create the COM object instance *before* you could call the Show() method.  Threading issues are associated with "class not registered" errors, make sure you C++ thread is STA.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that's a Windows Forms `Form.Show()`, I think you'll need a Windows Forms `Application.Run()` in your process somewhere.